# XML Error in storeviews Magento 1.9

Tags: xml

Hello i try to create an xml feed, but it works only in some of my store views.

I get the following error on line 419 at column 29: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0x1F 0x63 0x65 0x20